# Slow SQL: Select count of Table1 values missing from Table2

Tags: sql, performance, ms-access-2010

I am trying to return a count of the number of values from Table1 WHERE NOT EXISTS in Table2, I've got a query that seems correct but it's extremely slow to run:

```
SELECT count(container_no) 
FROM pier_data
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT 1 
    FROM Iron_mountain_data 
    WHERE pier_data.container_no = iron_mountain_data.[Customer Box Nbr]
    );
```

Is there any way I can speed this up?

Edit: For whatever reason I believe this **LEFT JOIN** business gave me the most expedient results in MS Access:

```
SELECT Count(container_no) AS boxes_missing_from_IM
FROM pier_data AS pd LEFT JOIN iron_mountain_data AS imd ON pd.container_no = 
imd.[Customer Box Nbr]
WHERE imd.[Customer Box Nbr] Is Null;
```

Comment: try using left join and put a where clause where not null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be better, try it :

```
SELECT COUNT(container_no) FROM pier_date
WHERE container_no NOT IN
(
     SELECT [Customer Box Nbr] FROM iron_mountain_data 
);
```

Also, as it has been suggested, you could use a left join with a where clause like this :

```
SELECT COUNT(container_no) FROM pier_date pd
LEFT JOIN iron_mountain_data imd ON pd.container_no = imd.[Customer Box Nbr]
WHERE imd.[Customer Box Nbr] IS NULL
```

The use of keyword 'DISTINCT' might be useful too like

```
COUNT(DISTINCT container_no)
```

or

```
SELECT DISTINCT [Customer Box Nbr]
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming [container_no] and [Customer box nbr] captures the same information

```
    SELECT  COUNT(container_no) 
    FROM pier_date pd
    WHERE   container_no NOT IN (
                                    SELECT DISTINCT [Customer Box Nbr] 
                                    FROM            iron_mountain_data
                                )
```

Comment: Answer already given except for keyword distinct that has also been suggested.

Answer (score 1):

Your query is fine, although I would use `COUNT(*)` and table aliases:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM pier_data as pd
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                  FROM Iron_mountain_data as imd
                  WHERE pd.container_no = imd.[Customer Box Nbr]
                 );
```

(These changes have no impact on performance, except for a very, very, very minor check that `container_no` is not `NULL` for the `COUNT()`.)

For performance, you want an index on `Iron_mountain_data([Customer Box Nbr])`:

```
create index idx_iron_mount_data_customer_box_nbr on Iron_mountain_data([Customer Box Nbr];
```

This should work for almost any way that you write the query.

Comment: TY, maybe it doesn't get much faster than that! I've tried this Indexing SQL but it doesn't seem to work in MS Access.